# Ruby: Get filename without the extensions

Tags: ruby

How can I get the filename without the extensions? For example, input of `"/dir1/dir2/test.html.erb"` should return `"test"`.

In actual code I will passing in `__FILE__` instead of `"/dir1/dir2/test.html.erb"`.

Comment: well in this case they are part of the filename. A dot is a perfectly legitimate character to have in a filename.

Comment: I may be using the wrong word "extensions". If so, please correct.  However, the question and outcome are legit. I'm shocked to see this down voted.

Comment: @l4mpi First of all, I do know about all the things you mentioned. Second, why are you judging? There are many ways to solve a problem. One of my purposes is to see if I'm missing something about File.basename or another method of the File class or if there are other better solutions. No question is a dump question, especially when someone is there to clarify it. Also, please don't assume I don't know about the basic things or read the docs.

Comment: Have you also read the description of the downvote button? "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful" - your question does only show a tiny amount of research (you've linked the first result for the google query `ruby filename`) and is hardly useful for anybody else either. It's even somewhat unclear as there is no such thing as multiple file extensions. And of course I assume you don't read the docs if the question doesn't give any indication of reading the docs. And I care because I want people to ask better questions - yours is frankly just not very good.

Comment: "filenames can have multiple extensions, usually representing nested transformations, such as files.tar.gz" and "Care should be taken when a file with multiple extensions... file world.imap.html will be associated with both the imap-file handler and text/html MIME-type" -- google those

Comment: I should have reworded that: There is no such thing as multiple extensions on a filesystem level (and on many filesystems, there isn't even a concept of an extension at all). Everything that you're quoting is a convention of specific applications like Apache et cetera. And regarding the `.tar.gz` ending, I'd even say it's wrong in this context: The file is a `.gz` file which just happens to contain a `.tar` file. The file type is `gz` and the fact that the filename contains `.tar` (or `txt`/`sqlite`/another `gz`/no other extension) is in no way useful before processing it with `gz` again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @xdazz and @Monk_Code for their ideas. In case others are looking, the final code I'm using is:

```
File.basename(__FILE__, ".*").split('.')[0]
```

This generically allows you to remove the full path in the front and the extensions in the back of the file, giving only the name of the file without any dots or slashes.

Answer (score 63):

Read documentation:

`basename(file_name [, suffix] ) → base_name`

> Returns the last component of the filename given in file_name, which
>   can be formed using both File::SEPARATOR and File::ALT_SEPARATOR as
>   the separator when File::ALT_SEPARATOR is not nil. **If suffix is given
>   and present at the end of file_name, it is removed.**

```
=> File.basename('public/500.html', '.html')
=> "500"
```

in you case:

```
=> File.basename("test.html.erb", ".html.erb")
=> "test"
```

Comment: This actually works for what I needed since I'm using `__FILE__` which gives the full file path.

Comment: @ChaseT. `__FILE__` this just shortcut for current file.

Comment: What I meant was that `__FILE__` is the full path to the current file, so I couldn't just use the other answer using split alone. File.basename gets rid of the stuff in front and back of the string for me.

Comment: This is a problem if you want to match multiple extensiosn

Comment: @Hedgehog it shouldn't.

Answer (score 34):

How about this

```
File.basename(f, File.extname(f))
```

returns the file name without the extension.. works for filenames with multiple '.' in it.

Comment: `File.basename("test.html.erb", File.extname("test.html.erb"))` returns `"test.html"`. Multiple `.` does not work in this case. The expected result would be `"test"` alone.

Answer (score 30):

In case you don't know the extension you can combine `File.basename` with `File.extname`:

```
filepath = "dir/dir/filename.extension"
File.basename(filepath, File.extname(filepath)) #=> "filename"
```

Comment: This does not work ofr the given use case: `.html.erb`

Comment: @Hedgehog you are right, but I'm sure my solution can help a lot of people that can come here attracted for title of the question looking for a more generic solution, as I did.

Answer (score 26):

[Pathname](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.3/libdoc/pathname/rdoc/Pathname.html) provides a convenient object-oriented interface for dealing with file names.

One method lets you replace the existing extension with a new one, and that method accepts the empty string as an argument:

```
>> Pathname('foo.bar').sub_ext ''
=> #<Pathname:foo>
>> Pathname('foo.bar.baz').sub_ext ''
=> #<Pathname:foo.bar>
>> Pathname('foo').sub_ext ''
=> #<Pathname:foo>
```

This is a convenient way to get the filename stripped of its extension, if there is one.

But if you want to get rid of all extensions, you can use a regex:

```
>> "foo.bar.baz".sub(/(?<=.)\..*/, '')
=> "foo"
```

Note that this only works on bare filenames, not paths like `foo.bar/pepe.baz`. For that, you might as well use a function:

```
def without_extensions(path)
  p = Pathname(path)
  p.parent / p.basename.sub(
    /
      (?<=.) # look-behind: ensure some character, e.g., for ‘.foo’
      \. # literal ‘.’
      .* # extensions
    /x, '')
end
```

Comment: With ` "foo.bar/pepe.baz".sub(/\..*/, '')` it fails

Comment: @juanfal Oh my, you are correct, thank you for letting me know! I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 9):

Split by dot and the first part is what you want.

```
filename = 'test.html.erb'
result = filename.split('.')[0]
```

Comment: I gave an upvote for the answer. However, since I'm using `__FILE__`, the File.basename method was what I needed.

Comment: So far this is the only solution that works for wildcards (given in the original use case) and multiple extensions.

Comment: `File.basename` will work if you will need to only get destination file name, but if you want to get all path name with dirs, for example, this answer will do.

Answer (score 2):

Considering the premise, the most appropriate answer for this case (and similar cases with other extensions) would be something such as this:

```
__FILE__.split('.')[0...-1].join('.')
```

Which will only remove the extension (not the other parts of the name: `myfile.html.erb` here becomes `myfile.html`, rather than just `myfile`.

Answer (score 1):

```
name = "filename.100.jpg"
puts "#{name.split('.')[-1]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet understanding it's not a multiplatform solution, it'd work for unixes:

```
def without_extensions(path)
    lastSlash = path.rindex('/')
    if lastSlash.nil?
        theFile = path
    else
        theFile = path[lastSlash+1..-1]
    end

    # not an easy thing to define
    # what an extension is
    theFile[0...theFile.index('.')]
end

puts without_extensions("test.html.erb")
puts without_extensions("/test.html.erb")
puts without_extensions("a.b/test.html.erb")
puts without_extensions("/a.b/test.html.erb")
puts without_extensions("c.d/a.b/test.html.erb")
```